# Creating smiley and adding expression

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

Here I created three smileys using CSS.

Fiddle - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/83CVQ/4/)

```
Should express Happy(this is there): <div id="smiley1">☻ </div>
Should express sad :<div id="smiley2">☻ </div> ?? 
Should express neutral<div id="smiley3">☻</div> ??
```

**Issues:**

1. All of them should be placed one after another (currently overlapping)
2. How to make it to express sad and neutral?

CSS:

```
#smiley1 {
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: red;
    width:350px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#smiley2 {
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: blue;
    width:350px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#smiley3 {
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: green;
    width:350px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: All three are smiling. There is no neutral or sad one in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the fonts, so you cannot change their moods using CSS, instead do it something like this, I made them from scratch..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQnL6/)

Here, I've used `:before` and `:after` pseudo to create the eyes of the smileys, and the nested `span` tag is used for the expression... I've not refactored my CSS, but you can chop it to a great extent by merging the common properties in a `class` and calling multiple classes on a single element.

```
.smiley {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.smiley:before {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    left: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.smiley:after {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    right: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.smiley span {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}










.neutral {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.neutral:before {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    left: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.neutral:after {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    right: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.neutral span {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 25px;
}










.sad {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.sad:before {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    left: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.sad:after {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    right: 15px;
    top: 30px;
}

.sad span {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Mr.Alien: I want to place all three in single line beside each other. Which element will do this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy Make the `div` `inline-block` like this `div.smiley, div.neutral, div.sad {
    display: inline-block;
}` http://jsfiddle.net/pQnL6/1/

Comment: This was a great solution. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, you cannot change the moods of the fonts with CSS and instead have to use other methods to create the smileys.

The method provided in Mr. Alien's answer is the best if you want to create really expressive smileys. But if that is not mandatory and you are fine with smileys as expressive as those in the question then you could use the below snippet.

In this method, we use:

- A `div` converted into a circle (using `border-radius`) as the face. You can change the `background-color` to the change the face color.
- Keyboard characters added to pseudo-elements, transformed and positioned using CSS to produce the required moods. The font used is Arial which is [very safe to use across platforms](http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html). The characters used are pretty much the ones that are regularly used for each smiley in chat (like `:-)` for smile, `:-(` for sad and `:-|` for indifferent/neutral etc)

```css
.smiley > div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 22.5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

:before,
:after {
  left: 0px;
  top: -2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transform-origin: bottm left;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.smile:after {
  content: ":-)";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.sad:after {
  content: ":-(";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.cry:after {
  content: "'";
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cry:before {
  content: ": (";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.wink:after {
  content: ";-)";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.indifferent:after {
  content: ":-\00a0";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.indifferent:before{
  content: "|";
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Just for presentation */

body {
  background-color: #282831;
  color: #999;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="smiley">
  <div class="smile"></div>
  <div class="sad"></div>
  <div class="indifferent"></div>
  <div class="cry"></div>
  <div class="wink"></div>
</div>
```

There is a larger collection of such smileys in my pen [**here**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/DujzJ).

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Font Awesome - icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/). There are a lot of icons.

Comment: icon does not express sad and neutral faces

Comment: Oh, okay. I can't see all of them. I saw that they offer a lot of images. You can request them about new icon here: http://fontawesome.io/community/#requesting-new-icons